# How to remove bumps in the motion of camera animation in graph editor?

Tags: animation, camera

Hi I'm very new to this blender. I wanted to recreate the title animation whose link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hn8juHOGCSI.

I tried to keyframe all the possible channels for camera motion, to match up the sequence between 18th to 24th second in the video, but I get weird jumps between 380 to 420 frame as well as between 480 to 520 frames, in the blend file that I have attached below.
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51803

Can anyone help me in the smooth transistion of camera animation as in the youtube link video.

Comment: Try the Follow Path Constraint for the camera: https://vimeo.com/171554266

Comment: ive oppened the file , intead of making soo many keyframes try to reduce them , it will help

Comment: When I try removing the keyframes, the camera gets shifted

Comment: At each keyframe blender is given an absolute camera position, then it tries to create a smooth transition between them. With lots of keyframes, you are making it hard for those transitions to be smooth, as you can never be as good at forming smooth curves with keyframes as Blender is. I suggest you remove some keyframes and edit the curve handles (in Graph Editor press tab, right click to select a key frame, right click and press G to move handles) so that you get the camera location where you want it in all frames.